# Add lines to visual selection via Ex-Mode

Tags: vim, restructuredtext

Is it possible to add certain lines to a visual selection via an EX-mode command?

I have text in the following form:

```
+----------+-----------+
| Some text| other text|
+----------+-----------+
| More text||
| And even more ||
| - ...||
+----------+-----------+
```

And I want the text to be displayed like this:

```
+---------------+------------+
| Some text     | other text |
+---------------+------------+
| More text     |            |
| And even more |            |
| - ...         |            |
+---------------+------------+
```

Using the tabular plugin when I delete the lines with + via the following workflow works:

```
g!/+/d
// Visually select the remaining lines
Tab /|
// Manually insert the +----+----+ lines
```

I was wondering if there is a way to keep the delimiting lines and visual-select the lines not containing a + via EX-Mode like `:g!/+/ add-line-to-visual-selection`.

Comment: There's a [multiselect](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=953) plugin, but I don't think Vim supports non-contiguous selections, otherwise. (I can't say whether Tabular will play nice with this plugin, either)

Comment: That's what I thought when neither `:h Visual` and `:h range` turned up something useful - well I really can not think of another case I ever missed that functionality so I can live using the ex-method.

Comment: This may be a stupid question (my SSH is down at the moment, so I can't test this!), but what happens if you visually select your whole table and `Tab \|`? If Tabular does screw the delimiter lines up, maybe you can use some kind of negative lookaround assertion in the parameter, so it ignores those lines.

Comment: Using `Tab /|` (`Tab \|` produces an `unrecognized command`) the following alignment is produces: https://gist.github.com/29184989de0d2ca8d4de . I actually might try negative lookahead/behind and see if that might help.

Comment: You could always just remove the misalignment with `gv` followed by `:'<,'>s/^\s*|/|/g`. Not elegant, I suppose, but it works... Note, however, that a "perfect" solution would also need to extend the delimiter lines so that they match up with your columns.

Comment: @Benoit - Well now you only have to post this as an answer, because it works - I guess I actually have to read the complete documentation for tabular, because I have not idea what `/|\|+/l1` does (especially the `\|` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
:Tab /|\|+/l1
:<range>g/+/s/ /-/g
```

You can find help for `\|` in `:help /\|` or more globally `:help pattern`, it is the standard way to express alternation in Vim Regular Expressions. So `/|\|+/` is a pattern with delimiters that matches either `|` or `+`. (Reading the whole `:help pattern` has excellent return on investment, FYI).

Concerning the `/l1` in the Tabular plugin, you can read the help of the plugin more in depth, it will add space after separator and left-align text.